# Functions not visible to Qunit

Tags: javascript, function, global-variables, qunit

Hello all I am new to JavaScript and working on the unit testing of my function using Quint framework.But I am stuck in a problem and need help from experts

Here is my problem

I have a file named calc.js like this

```
var calc; // global variable
(function(){
  calc = (function(){
        function calc(container, options) {
           this._container = container;
           this._jq_container = $(container);
           this._options = options || {};
           this.setupDefaults();

        }
        calc.prototype.setupDefaults = function() {
           var _self = this;
          _self._options.type = _self._options.type ? _self._options.type : 'add';
        };
        calc.prototype.add = function (val1, val2) { 
            return val1 + val2;
        };
        calc.prototype.sub = function (val1, val2) { 
            return val1 - val2;
        }; 
  return calc;
  })();
  $.fn.calc = function(options){
    this.each(function(){
      return new calc(this, options);
    });
  };
})();
```

now I have an html file of qunit some thing like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>QUnit Test Suite</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="qunit/qunit.css">
    <script src="qunit/qunit.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="test/javascript" src="calc.js"></script>   
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

test('add function test', function() { 

 equal(calc.add(2,4),"6" ,"function working correctly");
 /*I have also tried to access add function using some other method but alway got an error*/
});

});
</script>
</head>  
<body>  
    <h1 id="qunit-header">QUnit Test Suite</h1>  
    <h2 id="qunit-banner"></h2>  
    <div id="qunit-testrunner-toolbar"></div>  
    <h2 id="qunit-userAgent"></h2>  
    <ol id="qunit-tests"></ol>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Both my html and calc.js are in same file
And when I run this file I got an error that  calc is not defined

I dont under stand why as I have made calc global.
I have also tried using `window.calc = calc`but all in vain 
Can any one please guide me how can I access these function in my html test file
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: ignoring the QUnit aspect of this.. can you even just call a calc function from a script block?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code block in jsfiddle.net and your function call of `calc.add(2,4);` didn't run.

I changed the call to `calc.prototype.add(2,4)` and I could call your function as intended.  I suggest you add the `.prototype` to your QUnit test?